# IDEA 13 community can't debug Haxe

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, haxe

I use the IDEA13 community to work with the Haxe openFL. I had installed the Haxe plugin. I create a haxe project. I can run it with any target, such as Flash,HTML5, mac and so on. But I can't debug it with any target platform. To my surprise, I even not see the red point after I click the IDEA side which would appear a red point when I do the same in a java project.
Then I tried to use debug icon button to debug it. But nothing show me after the compile complete.
Can anybody know whether the IDEA13 support to debug Haxe project? if can, how can I set? 
I need help. 
I wish everyone goes well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the community plugin does not provide debugging for all the targets.

Currently only flash and an experimental cpp debugger(tivo fork) are the only implementations provided.

For html5 the plugin requires work to integrate with idea's javascript debugger. You can however use the Haxe generated source maps for break points on Haxe source code within the chrome developer tools.

There is activity for this plugin on github so it may just be a matter of time.